# How to secure Linux terminal with Google Authenticator?

Tags: passwords, linux

How to secure Linux terminal with [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) for root access and login?

Comment: this is really a superuser type question

Comment: plus TONS of results for the Google query: "linux google authenticator"

Comment: May not be suitable for enterprise deployments since it uses shared secrets:  https://www.wikidsystems.com/blog/5-issues-enterprises-should-consider-before-using-google-authenticator-for-ssh/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tried it, but I believe you can use Google Authenticator's PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module). It is a part of [Google Authenticator OpenSource](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator) project. You can find more details on it at their [Github - PAM Module Instructions](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/PAM-Module-Instructions).

Quick Google Search gave me this article: [How To Set Up Multi-Factor Authentication for SSH on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-14-04), which you might find helpful.